# Chrome Tab Group Migration/Sync

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

Since Google rolled out the grouping of tabs feature, I have made heavy use of it. It has helped me reduce the number of Chrome windows I need open as I can shrink the group to reduce the number of tabs in a window at a given time.

I need to rebuild my Windows 10 PC and need to take these groups with me. This would be a one-time migration/sync, but if there is a way to sync them always, I'd be interested, but I don't want them to open on other computers, just be available for me to click and open as required.

Before tab groups, I would save each window to its own folder, let Chrome sync the bookmarks and then sign in to Chrome on the new computer and open each folder in its own window. If I do this now, I would lose my tab groups as I don't see a way to save the tab group bookmarks only unless done individually.

I have looked at several extensions but they either sync their own "groups" or if they look at the groups in Chrome, they don't sync.

Comment: It looks like there will be an option to save tab groups to the bookmarks in one of the next updates: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2998406/4..6 - maybe you could enroll into beta?

Comment: @1NN that looks promising... wonder how long the wait is. Can I switch without losing my tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have selected "Pick up where I left off" in Settings, the last two chrome sessions are saved in:
`C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sessions`

You can just migrate that folder to your new setup, and the next chrome session will start where you left off, including groups. You might have to replace `Default` in the above path with your custom profile name.

This will not migrate any other settings, so you might want consider to copy the whole containing folder with all of chrome's settings.

Comment: Right, let me give this a go...

Comment: Worked perfectly in my test VM so I am happy to proceed. Thanks!