# How do I restore a lost or previous session in Brave (Chromium) browser?

Tags: restore, chromium, browser-tabs, session, brave

I **MUST** find an answer to this, folks, **PLEASE HELP ME!**

I lost all my pinned, grouped AND standalone tabs in Brave (Chromium) browser, right after the browser locked up and crashed. Upon browser restart, I started from scratch and pinned only a few crucial tabs. But that's not optimal for me — **how do I restore a *previous*, properly working session?**

Thank you 1,000,000 times for the solution to this!

- Brave Browser version: 1.35.100; Chromium: 98.0.4758.87 (Official
  Build) (64-bit)
- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Home Build 19041
- System Type: x64-based PC
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2592 Mhz, 4
  Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: Chrome saves the two last sessions. I don't know if it is the same for brave, but check the following answer, you might be able to find the exact folder location for Brave https://superuser.com/a/1668842/714576

Comment: "how do I restore a previous, properly working session?" - **You cannot** The session was lost due to the crash, there isn't anything to restore, the session file were never saved.  Once you reopened your browser without those session files the session was permanently lost.